# Unwanted hover event seen on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

I am playing with very strange problem. I have implemented the list view with collapsible menu.

For desktop browsers I have added hover event and styling for the li. It is working fine there.

But encounter the strange problem when I trying to run it on mobile safari.

When I scroll the list I found at specific point on device, the hover event getting called and it leads to collapse the li to sub menus.

I observed that it is only the specific point to which I need to scroll the li. Then automatically it is expanding.

Ideally on device the li should expand only on click event.

Is there any way to remove unwanted hover event on mobile safari?

Comment: Code ? Demo ? Fiddle ?

Comment: It is just a simple collapsible control for e.g. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ . I am wondering about that point in mobile safari where actual hover event applied .